# Then every composition factor of $W/(\ker(\alpha)+\ker(\beta))$ is a composition factor of both $U,V$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

$k$ is commutative ring and $A$ is a $k$-algebra. Let $U,V$ be $A$-modules having composition series. Let $W$ be a submodule of $U \oplus V$. Denote by $\alpha: W \to U$ and $\beta: W \to V$ the components of the inclusion map $W \to U\oplus V$. Then every composition factor of $W/(\ker(\alpha)+\ker(\beta))$ is a composition factor of both $U,V$.

I really don't quite follow the last sentence. If I'm correct, I understand that every composition factor of $W/(\ker(\alpha)+\ker(\beta))$ is a composition factor of $U \oplus V$. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hints:** 1) $W$ has a composition series as well.

2. If $S_1>S_2$ are submodules of a module $M$, then composition factors of $M/S_1$ are composition factors of $M/S_2$.
3. $\ker\alpha+\ker\beta$ contains $\ker \alpha$ and $\ker\beta$.